# what is Created a new custom field in the user profile?

Tags: wordpress

[Check out this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN7Cm.png)

I am using WP activity Log plugin to monitor an admin's activity in the site. So I've just come accorss this particular log which I actually can't understand.

So, can anyone please help me explain the log ?

Answer (score 0):

It means that a user called **pluck** with administrator privileges has created a new custom field called `ast-minimum-addon-version-notice-min-ver` with a value of 3.1.0

Comment: Alright. I get it. But why he created that particular field ? That's what I'm not getting -_-

Comment: He has set a mimnum version number, presumabely for a plugin, for which if the installed version is below then a notification is shown. Of course this is pure speculation, based on the field name, to get an absolute answer you would have to search the codebase for where the field is referenced